# Generic return value (java)

Tags: java, generics, return-value

This works nicely:

```
// Return all objects with code 'code'.
static List<? extends ICode> getObjects(String code, List<? extends ICode> list)
{
  <ICode> retValue = new ArrayList<ICode>();
  for (ICode item : list)
  { 
    if (item.getCode().equals(code))
    {
        retValue.add(item);
    }
  }
  return retValue;
}
```

The 'singular' version can be:

```
// Return the first object found with code 'code'.
static ICode getObject(String code, List<? extends ICode> lijst)
{
  for (ICode item : lijst)
{
     if (item.getCode().equals(code)) return item;
}
return null;
}
```

But instead of return value `ICode` I would like return value `<? extends ICode>`.
Can it be done?

See Jon Skeets answer, I now prefer to use the T instead of ? also in the plural version:

```
// Return all objects with code 'code'.
    public static <T extends ICode> List<T> getObjects(String code, List<T> lijst)
    {
        List<T> retValue = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T item : lijst)
        {
        if (item.getCode().equals(code))
        {
        retValue.add(item);
        }
      }
      return retValue;
    }
```

Comment: There's a typo in your first version of getObjects - your copy/paste omitted the type List on the declaration of retValue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want it to be the same type as the actual list. In that case, this should do it:

```
static <T extends ICode> T getObject(String code, List<T> list)
{
  for (T item : list)
  {
     if (item.getCode().equals(code)) return item;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: compiler says 'set method return type to T':
static <T extends ICode> T getObject
a rather strange notation

Comment: strange that item.getCode() works, because as an input parameter it has not been declared that T implements ICode. Only for the return value??

Comment: Wait a minute, I see the light. The first declaration is for the whole method signature, the following T is the one-character return value and the declaration also holds for T in the parameter list.

Comment: Yes. It's the same type anywhere `T` is mentioned in the entire method.

Comment: Even if you had a list of lists you'd want to ditch the wildcard in the return type: `static List<Code> findObjects(String name, List<? extends List<? extends Code>> list)`.

Comment: Is there a name for `<T extends ICode>`? I hate whenever I have to explain this to someone in long-winded sentences instead of a word or two.

Comment: @NobleUplift: Well its a bounded type parameter, if that helps.

Comment: Googled the phrase and the first two links were already in my history. ... apparently I already knew this. Bookmark so I don't forget again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you let the return type be ICode then you can return any type that extends ICode.

Comment: Which is not the same... Consider: a class `Subcode` which extends/implements `ICode` and `List<Subcode> list = ...`, then you can do `Subcode foo = getObject("foo", list)` but you would have to do `foo = (Subcode)getObject("foo", list)` with your solution.

Comment: Correct, an extra cast is necessary. Compare to the List<? extends ICode> where a cast is not necessary.